# Get random line from .txt file then remove the line from .txt file

Tags: node.js

need some help on this one.
I'm creating a Discord bot in Node.js.

What i that to do:

> Read a random line from a local .txt file.
>
> Then forward it to Discord (I know how)
>
> Then delete that exact line i got, from the local .txt file.

Almost like an array. But, a local one, that i can always fast edit.

I'm still new to Node and Javascript, so i learn by trying and reading, but i got stuck here, that's why i need to professional help :-)

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjRXA.png)

Hope i made you understand my problem, and you can help me.

I have the following:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let randomNumber = 
fs.readFileSync('./resources/array.txt').toString().split("\n");
let item = randomNumber[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomNumber.length)];
```

Which outputs random number from the file.

Comment: What did you try? It's important to show what you've done to solve your problem. Even reading the file in and having an array is a big first step that'd take you a lot closer to your solution. If you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: I edited the post. That's what i have right now.

Comment: As a note, code that re-writes files is inherently risky, as mid-way through re-writing it could crash and lose all data. Could you do this with something light-weight like a SQLite DB? Those are much friendlier to operate on, and easy to use if you know basic SQL.

Comment: I'll need to investigate that. But i'll try look into it.

Comment: But.. Another way to do it.. Import the data from the text file, create an Array from file. Then, when i get the random number, it will delete it from the array, that would also work for me.

Comment: Sounds like you have a solution, it's just a case of breaking that down into code. Maybe use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the file isn't too big and isn't being appended to during the running of this script, you could take your data, store it in memory, make your change to the array, remove all data from your text file, and rewrite the data from the array to your file

```
const fs = require('fs'); // use const **
const data = fs.readFileSync('./array.txt');
const splitData = data.split('\n');
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * splitDate.length);
const line = splitData.splice(randomNumber, 1); ***
fs.writeFileSync('./array.txt', splitData.splice.join('\n'); ****
console.log(line); // random line
```

** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

**** https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Comment: This would delete the whole array, and only keep the random number, i just want to remove than 1 line which contains the random number.